# UI Router loading route but not component - Upgrade issue

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

So we've been using Angular UI router for a while since we were running hybrid with AngularJS

And now that i'm finally at the point to remove AngularJS, i'm moving the 'error' and 'auth' pages towards Angular instead of AngularJS.

Our system exists out of multiple user types so we've split our routes the same way, we have core -> for shared
admin -> for admins
etc.

Now when I create a new route

core.error.not-found

Having a core route and an error route. The route loads, but the attached component does not load.

When I remove core from the name so that it becomes error.not-found. It suddenly works! (Al though the navigation doesn't)

Same goes for admin.news etc.
Somehow now that we're no longer using hybrid, child routes are no longer loading their components.

I've attached a sample project here:
https://github.com/SamanthaAdrichem/uirouter-issues-test

If for example you remove admin. from the news path in: `src/app/admin/routes.enum.ts:4`
or remove core. from all the error paths in: `src/app/core/routes.enum.ts:9` they start working

It's probably something super simple that i'm missing / not seeing :(

As for updating to the latest version, that's currently not possible, our entire app breaks on Angular 13 because of AngularJS and removing AngularJS and also upgrading to Angular 13/14/15 is too big a change (small steps)

**[edit]:** It seems like there is something going wrong while targeting the view, when it was still hybrid with AngularJs it always used the main view, now it's trying to find a non existing child view.

**[edit2]:** Definitely target view, instead of using

`component: ComponentRef`

Using

```
        views: {
            '!$default': <Ng2ViewDeclaration>ErrorComponent
        }
```

Fixes the issue... So we need to find a way to set the default target view for all routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So ui router uses child views for child routes by default, as far as I've seen you can not change this, nor does it give an error if the view does not exists. (While when running Hybrid, it does not do this)

If you just want to work with a root view, defining that view for the component is not enough, you'd need to make it mandatory by adding an exclamation mark.

So your current definition should change from

```
    {
        name: 'auth.login',
        url: '/login?:target',
        params: {
            target: {dynamic: true, value: ''},
        },
        component: LoginComponent,
        permissions: null,
        requiresAuth: false
    },
```

Towards

```
    {
        name: 'auth.login',
        url: '/login?:target',
        params: {
            target: {dynamic: true, value: ''},
        },
        views: {'!$default': {component: LoginComponent}},
        permissions: null,
        requiresAuth: false
    },
```

You can choose to name the view
`<ui-view name="root"></ui-view>`

so you can use that instead of `$default`

```
views: {'!root': {component: LoginComponent}},
```